# How to create DOM component with start and end tag in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Here, I create a component `SomeComponent`

```js
const SomeComponent = () => (
    <div className={"some-class"}>
        some text here
    </div>
)
```

I can use this component like this:

```js
<SomeComponent text={"here is some text"} />
```

I would like to do the same thing, but with an opening and closing tag, as below:

```js
<SomeComponent>
    here is some text
</SomeComponent>
```

How can I acheive this?

Many thanks - Oli

Comment: `className={"some-class"}` could be simplified to `className="some-class"` or even `class="some-class"`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I am aware. I see others do it like this, so this is how I chose to post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access "contents" as `children` property.

```
const SomeComponent = ({ children }) => (
    <div className={"some-class"}>
      {children}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`children` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment) like this:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ children }) => (
    <div className="some-class">
        {children}
    </div>
)
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<SomeComponent>whatever content here</SomeComponent>
```

`children` prop takes not just strings, and these also work:

```
<SomeComponent>
  <div>hey</div>
</SomeComponent>

<SomeComponent>
  {arrayOfComponents}
</SomeComponent>
```

Comment: `children` can be anything, not just renderable objects. Depending on usage you might run into trouble. If I where to pass a component and try to render it, an error is thrown however if I use it as an element it works without issue, whereas a normal object or string doesn't. As an example `({children: Component}) => <div><Component value="Hello World!" /></div>` expects a component (function or class) This can then be called with for example `<SomeComponent>{({value}) => <button>{value}</button>}</SomeComponent>`.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is look for the `children` props.

```
const SomeComponent = ({ children }) => (
    <div className="some-class">
        { children }
    </div>
);
```

Where children can be text, HTML or other React components.